# WOLF RX-50 Scooter problems

Tags: scooter

I got a brand new moped I bought, it is the WOLF RX-50 2018 White Version. It is a 4 stroke 50cc engine. My problems started happening at around 300 miles. It used to just lose all power when driving normally, turn off when stopped. Now when I drive it I have to "blip" the throttle to keep it alive otherwise it will turn off. After driving it for 10-30 minutes I can feel the engine get weaker to where blipping the throttle no longer keeps it alive so it just dies when I give it throttle. Every time it dies it does not start right back up but if I sit with it for 5 minutes it starts perfectly fine. I don't know what could be wrong, I was thinking carb issues.

Comment: did you tinker with anything at all? Something brand new should not have such issues. Did you try to see online if anyone else had a similar issue? Sometimes products will have chronical issues that are present in most if not all of the particular batch of a given model.